# How to define factory with specific random choice for Django model?

Tags: django, django-models, factory-boy

i would like to define a factory class for a User django model like this :

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

but for all fields, i would like to have a fake value from Faker or None because the model allow null. Ideally, the choice between fake value and None is made by probability for example 90% for fake value and 10% for none. i guess a factory like this

```
class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    name = factory.Faker("random_choice", elements=[factory.Faker("name"), None], p=[0.90, 0.10]))
    created_date = factory.Faker("random_choice", elements=[factory.Faker("date"), None], p=[0.90, 0.10]))
```